# what toolset is used to create these cool animations and interesting page design?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i’ve found this awesome website:
[waaark.com](http://waaark.com)

i noticed the people behind it are web design geniuses. can anyone identify what tools are used to create their impressive animations and full screen pages with cool transitions?

im unable to determine wether this is a vanilla html/css/js website or if they are using some cool toolset i have yet to learn about! i also noticed that they are using wordpress? how is wordpress being used here?

Comment: They use [greensock.com](https://greensock.com/)

Comment: @t.niese really? how so...

Comment: @t.niese also is just a static html/css/js website? how are the pages designed to fill the screen like that?

Comment: The question is way to broad to be answered. The given site is a complex construct, and has multiple parts, and each of them could be an own question. StackOverflow is a place to ask question about specific problems you have with your current code.

Comment: @t.niese where does my question belong sir.

Comment: Don't know. If I have these kind I broad question, I start to do some research on my own, check what alternatives libraries exists, compare them, read their docs to check how they are used, and then if I have a specific problem about using those libraries I come here to ask a question.

Comment: @t.niese alright thank you. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the source code or you can use a tool like Wappalyzer: https://www.wappalyzer.com/

You just write the URL of the web page you want to analyze. Wappanalyzer says that it's using Wordpress, typekit, greensock, and jquery. If you take a look at the source code, you can see that it's right.

Comment: That is a very cool looking tool, thanks for posting the link.